# After I changed ID Javascript, not working next "click" event, what is the problem?

Tags: javascript

```
let x = ["1", "3", "5"]

$("#button").click(
  function num() {
    $("#answers").html(x[0])
    document.getElementById("button").setAttribute("id", "button2");
  }
)

$("#button2").click(
  function num2() {
    $("#answers").html(x[1])
    document.getElementById("button").setAttribute("id", "button3");
  }
)

$("#button3").click(
  function num3() {
    $("#answers").html(x[2])
  }
)
```

Comment: Please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and indent it properly to make it readable.

Comment: `$("#button2").click(…)` installs an event listener on the element that *currently* has the id `button2`. If there exists no such element, no event listener will be installed. Changing ids afterwards does not help, your `#button` is still the same element and has the original listeners attached to it.

Comment: you also need semicolons after the click method `.click(...);`

Comment: Instead of using three different listeners, use a state variable that stores the index of the `x` value to use in the html.

Comment: @Ifaruki Semicolons are optional ([if you know what you're doing](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons)). Here, it works fine without.

Comment: @Bergi i should read that, usually i press CTRL+S and prettier format my code and adds semicolons

Answer (score 3):

When you have this:

```
$("#button2").click(.......
```

... that will look at #button2 right *now*, not at some future renaming. Since at the start there is no such `id`, this `.click` method is not doing anything.

You can achieve this with [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), but in your case I would go for a different solution.

Changing the `id` attribute of a DOM element is really bad practice. Instead use a variable which will determine in which "case" you are, and just use one click handler where you inspect that variable. Something like this:

```
var state = 1;

$("#button").click(function num() {
    if (state == 1) {
        $("#answers").html(x[0]);
        state = 2; // move to the next state..
    } else if (state == 2) {
        // do something else...
        state = 3;
    } else if (state == 3) {
        // ... etc ...
    }
})
```

If the logic is really so simple that you want to just display the next entry in the `x` array, then let the `state` be that index:

```
var index = 0;

$("#button").click(function num() {
    $("#answers").html(x[index]);
    index = (index+1) % x.length;  // round robin selection of array value
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add current index and your code will be simple:

```
let x = ["1","3","5"]
let currentIndex = -1

$("#button").click(() => {
    currentIndex += 1
    $("#answers").html(x[currentIndex])
  }
)
```

See in playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/x0sq6fry/6/